# How can I create a spacial grid?

Tags: collision-detection, javascript

I just created a tile map for my game, and its a side profile game. The game looks sort of like Terraria, where there is blocks you can place and break. I want the player to be able to collide with the blocks, and I don't know how to achieve something like this.

The game is in Javascript but I can understand other languages so feel free to give examples in the language of your choice.

Comment: Man, so many questions that can be answered by modding Minecraft. <3  The way MC handles this is that "block" and "item" are singletons, where `ItemStack` is the object that shows up in the inventory: it holds a pointer to the block/item singleton and stores a count (plus has some other methods, like what to do when the user right-clicks with it, and so on).

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple platformer that used rectangle collision in order to detect if the player is currently colliding with a tile. I made the game in c# but I believe the concept will be the same for Javascript. Here are the steps I took:

1: Create a new class named **Tile**

2: Generate a list of **Tile**s in order to fill up the tilemap

3: Run a loop through each tile to determine if the player is colliding with the tile.

```
                player.Left <= rectangle.Right &&
                player.Right >= rectangle.Left &&
                player.Top <= rectangle.Bottom &&
                player.Bottom >= rectangle.Top
```

4: If the previous condition returns true, determine if the player's midpoint is above/below/to the left of/to the right of the tile's midpoint. (This is used to determine if the tile is being used as the ground, a wall, or the ceiling)

5: Manipulate Player's position according to step 4

There is a more optimal way of detecting collision, but I found this method the easiest to understand.